# MySQL 8.0 GROUP BY / FULL_GROUP_BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Since upgrading to MySQL 8 I have a lot of queries that dont comply to the new full-group-by setting of MySQL. Below is a simplified version of one of the queries. I have A LOT of them and before going through all the code, I want to fully understand the problem.

I have the following records in the database:

```
[prod_id] => 1
[prod_name] => Product 1
[prod_new] => 50.00
[prod_size] => L

[prod_id] => 2
[prod_name] => Product 1
[prod_new] => 45.00
[prod_size] => M

[prod_id] => 3
[prod_name] => Product 1
[prod_new] => 40.00
[prod_size] => S

[prod_id] => 4
[prod_name] => Product 4
[prod_new] => 100.00
[prod_size] => M

[prod_id] => 5
[prod_name] => Product 5
[prod_new] => 200.00
[prod_size] => M
```

When I ran the following query in MySQL 5.x, I got 3 results. Containing products 1, 4, 5. With the corresponding name, price and size.

```
SELECT prod_id, prod_name, prod_price, prod_size 
FROM prod_product
GROUP BY prod_name
```

Since the upgrade I get the widely know error about nonaggregated columns. So I want to fix this, but in some cases this will get me unwanted results. Lets say, for some reason, I wanted the highest product-id.

```
SELECT MAX(prod_id), prod_name, ANY_VALUE(prod_price), ANY_VALUE(prod_size)
FROM prod_product
GROUP BY prod_name
```

This will give me product-id's 3, 4, 5. But with product-id 3 it gives me the price and size of product-id 1.

Obviously that is unwanted behaviour. I would assume that, since `prod_id` is the primary-key, the database knows which values to show with the corresponding id. When I say `MAX(prod_id)` this already pinpoints a single record in this group, why give me values of other records from this group?

I guess I am missing something important here. =)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I would assume that, since prod_id is the primary-key, the database knows which values to show with the corresponding id.

Why would it know that?

Consider the following queries:

```
SELECT prod_name, prod_id, MIN(prod_price), MAX(prod_price)
FROM prod_product
GROUP BY prod_name
```

Which value should it return for `prod_id` here? The product that corresponds to the minimum price? Or the product that corresponds to the maximum price?

Also, what if there are multiple products that tie for the minimum or maximum price? Which one should it return?

```
SELECT prod_name, prod_id, AVG(prod_price)
FROM prod_product
GROUP BY prod_name
```

Now which `prod_id` should it infer? The aggregate calculation `AVG()` is likely to return a value that doesn't correspond to any single product.

The same happens with the aggregate `SUM()`.

The fact is, there is no implicit correlation between an aggregate function and a specific row in the group. You should not expect SQL to guess which row from the group you mean to reference when you use non-aggregated expressions.

Comment: I understand that, but since I am only selecting one record, based on the primary key (not on other columns), I would assume that mysql doesnt just pick random other records for the other columns. In fact the resultset should be limited by max(prod_id), whats obviously not the case when you do avg(). If the group result would consist of multiple records I would say that that could lead to an error, but in this case the primary key _could_ limit the group result to one record.

Comment: Using `GROUP BY` defines the groups of rows over which to calculate aggregates. There are multiple rows in that group, at least potentially, and in your example, there are in fact multiple rows per group. So referencing a column in the group without using any aggregate function means it is ambiguous which row to take that value from. This is an error in standard SQL, and in most RDBMS products that implement SQL (only MySQL and SQLite are exceptions).

Comment: I guess that is kind of my point. When I am using MAX(prod_id) I define a single row in that group. It _feels_ ambiguous to also use aggregate functions on the other colums. Especially when those functions give results not corresponding to the primary key (prod_id) that is selected by the first aggregate function (ie MAX(prod_id)).

I am not talking about AVG() or MAX(prod_price), or any other aggregate that could leave room for multiple records. I just want ONE record from that group.

Comment: What do you think about the example of querying MIN(prod_id) and MAX(prod_id) in the same query? Which prod_id is the designated prod_id for the group, which should be returned if you reference prod_id in another column without an aggregate function?

Comment: Ofcourse, that example should give an error, or maybe even just no result at all. I mean, that is just noncence. Like doing WHERE prod_id > 10 AND prod_id < 10.

MySQL cant confirm to that request, but it should on a single MIN(prod_id).

Comment: Well, it doesn't, and neither does the ANSI SQL standard, or any other implementation of SQL. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first record in every group of rows having the same `prod_name` ordered by `prod_id`,  you can use *window function* `ROW_NUMBER()`, which is available in MySQL 8 :

```
SELECT x.prod_id, x.prod_name, x.prod_new, x.prod_size
FROM (
    SELECT 
        p.prod_id, p.prod_name, p.prod_new, p.prod_size, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.prod_name ORDER BY p.prod_id) rn
    FROM prod_product p
) x WHERE x.rn = 1
```

The inner query assigns a number to each record within each group, and the outer query filters in the first record in each group.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fY9avW1ZFFn3hyfnZxfjoM/0)** :

```
WITH prod_product AS (
    SELECT 1 prod_id, 'Product 1' prod_name, 50 prod_new, 'L' prod_size
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Product 1', 45, 'M'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Product 1', 40, 'S'
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'Product 4', 100, 'M'
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'Product 5', 200, 'M' 
)
SELECT x.prod_id, x.prod_name, x.prod_new, x.prod_size
FROM (
    SELECT 
        p.prod_id, p.prod_name, p.prod_new, p.prod_size, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.prod_name ORDER BY p.prod_id) rn
    FROM prod_product p
) x WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

```
| prod_id | prod_name | prod_new | prod_size |
| ------- | --------- | -------- | --------- |
| 1       | Product 1 | 50       | L         |
| 4       | Product 4 | 100      | M         |
| 5       | Product 5 | 200      | M         |
```